# Entity Framework "A relationship multiplicity constraint violation occurred"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I received this error from Entity Framework this morning:

*A relationship multiplicity constraint violation occurred: An EntityReference can have no more than one related object, but the query returned more than one related object. This is a non-recoverable error.*

The error refers to a very simple One-To-Many relationship between `User` and `Address`

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
} 

public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Fluent API to configure the relationship between entities, but in this case the relationship seems to simple that at first I didn't specify any particular rule and I let EF "deduce" the relationship:

```
public class AddressConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
{
    public AddressConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(a => a.Id);
        Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
    }
}

public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(u => u.Id);
        Property(u => u.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

But after receiving the error I tried to specify the following rule in the AddressConfiguration:

```
public class AddressConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
{
    public AddressConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(a => a.Id);
        Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
        HasOptional(x => x.User).WithMany(); // I tried adding this
    }
}
```

After doing that, I tried generating a new automatic migration, and this is what I obtained:

```
public partial class AddressFixMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Addresses", "User_Id", "dbo.Users");
        AddColumn("dbo.Addresses", "User_Id1", c => c.Guid());
        CreateIndex("dbo.Addresses", "User_Id1");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Addresses", "User_Id1", "dbo.Users", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Addresses", "User_Id1", "dbo.Users");
        DropIndex("dbo.Addresses", new[] { "User_Id1" });
        DropColumn("dbo.Addresses", "User_Id1");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Addresses", "User_Id", "dbo.Users", "Id");
    }
}
```

I found this very odd. The Db seemed ok even before, with the Addresses Table having a Foreign Key "User_Id", but after specifying the one-to-many relationship in the Configuration file EF wants to create a *different* Foreign Key. Why??

I also tried to  specify `HasOptional(x => x.User).WithMany().Map(x => x.MapKey("User_Id"));`, but in that case when I try to create the automatic migration I receive the following error:

*User_Id: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'User_Id' is already defined.*

It seems like something is clearly wrong with my DB, but I can't see what and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I needed to change my Configuration file as it follows:

```
public class AddressConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
{
    public AddressConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(a => a.Id);
        Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
        HasOptional(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.Addresses).Map(x => x.MapKey("User_Id"));
    }
}
```

`.WithMany()` (without parameter) is for when there is no navigation property on the other side of the relationship, while in this case I needed to spacify `.WithMany(x => x.Addresses)` because `User` actually contains a list of Addresses.

Answer (score 0):

There are other techniques, but I prefer to put the FK in explicitly:

```
public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Int? User_Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Then use this fluent code:

```
HasOptional(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.Addresses).HasForeignKey(x => x.User_Id);
```

Comment: I can't change the architecture of the domain, there is a reason why we made this choice. Also, why would your suggested change work? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You don't need to. If User_Id is the FK, just add it to your model and tell the fluent code. EF tries to add User_Id1 because it can't determine the relationship.

Comment: Ok I just tried what you said, and the result when I try to create the migration is identical: `AddForeignKey("dbo.Addresses", "User_Id1", "dbo.Users", "Id")`. This is rather odd, it's like the column is corrupt or something like thiat.

Comment: Omg I just changed `.WithMany()` to `.WithMany(x => x.Addresses)` and it started working! No migration was created and the error disappeared. I don't understand: shouldn't `x => x.Addresses` have been implicit?

Comment: There are lots of EF stuff that can be implicit, like UserId automatically known as a FK, but I personally think it makes it clearer to other programmers to just do it explicitly. Generally you don't look at that stuff unless a problem pops up.