# Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'CW_FirmaCommunication_CwFirma_Source' in relationship 'CW_FirmaCommunication_CwFirma'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, one-to-many, ef-fluent-api

I have the following problem:

I have a company (CW_Firma) which can have 0 to many ways to contact them (CW_FirmaCommunication).
I am using EntityFramework and FluentAPI to create the relationship.

I have the following code :

```
[Table("dbo.CW_Firma")]
public class CW_Firma
{
    [Key]
    [Column("F_VAT")]
    public int VatNumber { get; set; }
}

[Table("dbo.CW_FirmaCommunication")]
public class CW_FirmaCommunication
{
    [Key]
    [Column("FC_VAT")]
    public int VatNumber { get; set; }
    [Column("FC_Data")]
    public string FC_Data { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CW_FirmaCommunication>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.CwFirma)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.VatNumber);
}
```

When I run my code, I get the following exception :

> Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'CW_FirmaCommunication_CwFirma_Source' in relationship 'CW_FirmaCommunication_CwFirma'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'

I have been searching the internet, looking at different solutions here on StackOverflow, but nothing seems to resolve my problem.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and trying, this is what I ended up with and what works fine:

```
public class CW_FirmaCommunication
{
    [Key]
    public int FC_ID { get; set; }
    public int FC_VAT { get; set; }
    public int FC_Type { get; set; }
    public string FC_Data { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FC_VAT")]
    public virtual CW_Firma CwFirma { get; set; }
}

public class CW_Firma
{
    [Key]
    public int F_VAT { get; set; }
}
```

And I removed the code from the "OnModelCreating".

Answer (score 0):

1. you use fluent api and mapping annotations - I would prefer to use only one,
2. in annotation mapping you declared that field VatNumber of CW_FirmaCommunication table is primary key (as VatNumber in CW_Firma), which means that you have relation 1:1 while using fluent api you want 1:many.

Basing on your code I made few corrects:

```
[Table("dbo.CW_FirmaCommunication")]
public class CW_FirmaCommunication
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Communnication_Id")]
    public int CommunicationId { get; set; }

    [Column("FC_VAT")]
    public int VatNumber { get; set; }

    public CW_Firma Firma { get; set; }

    [Column("FC_Data")]        
    public string FC_Data { get; set; }
}
```

I have added seperate PK for communications table (not FC_VAT), and added navigation property Firma.

New mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CW_FirmaCommunication>()
            .HasRequired<CW_Firma>(c => c.Firma)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.VatNumber);
```

It's working in my test db.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks, but how can I make it so my problem is solved? I tried removing the "Key" from CW_FirmaCommunication" but I still get the same error.

Comment: I've changed my code to what you wrote, but now I'm getting : A relationship multiplicity constraint violation occurred: An EntityReference can have no more than one related object, but the query returned more than one related object. This is a non-recoverable error.

Comment: @BartSchelkens do you mean you have created tables in db and that new error is during quering data? In my tests tables had created. Maybe clear both tables and create them from start.

Comment: I'm using an existing database. So I didn't create the tables, they were already there.

Comment: in the CW_Firma it is F_VAT in the CW_FirmaCommunications it is FC_VAT. Which one do you mean? In CW_Firma the F_VAT is unique. In the CW_FirmaCommuncations the FC_VAT is not unique.

Comment: I don't know. It working ok in my tests - I can add and query data. But maybe this post will helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000646/entity-framework-a-relationship-multiplicity-constraint-violation-occurred

Comment: One curiosity: [Key] attribute creates identity column: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/key-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx, but you have db with created tables therefore it is not problem for you.